# How to create a calculator that has 3 drop-down lists instead of buttons?

Tags: html

I want to create a calculator, in HTML, that has 3 drop-down lists and 3 sets of 6 fields.

I created a simple calculator a few years ago that had fields instead of buttons.. but I forgot how I made it.

The idea is to have 3 drop-down lists with 17 options each and a value for each option(some options will have up to 3 values). I want them to show the value/s, when selected, in specific fields of the 6 fields in set1, set2 will be a input set of fields and set3 will show the sum of set1 and set2.

If it can't be done in HTML only, It would be OK if there were input fields, aswell, instead of drop-down lists, here, the user would input a specific text, case sensitive, that might have 3 values which will have to appear in 3 specific fields(out of the 6 fields from set1(say field 1, 3 and 4) and some values will have to add up to some values already in whichever field.

I hope it is understandable.

Comment: too much words.... try simple drawing or jsfiddle.net

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to implement a calculator with buttons, so is your specific problem on how to do dropdown lists?

Comment: only using html , you can't create such a thing that calculates or that have a logic of computation , because html is used for presentation not calculation...

Answer (score 0):

You need the HTML  element: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

To process, you'll either need javascript or some server-side programming language to process. Depending on what technology you use, there will be a different way of handling the selected values. You may want to look into jQuery's (javascript-based) methods of form handling documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/forms/

Comment: I got as far as making a simple calculator with input fields only.. that's the "highest" I ever reached, but that was about 3 years ago.. and I can't remember if I used javascript or anything else and I can't remember how I created it in the first place :S Thank you though, I will create a sketch in paint, anyway, to show what I want to create.

Comment: Any technology will take some time getting used to. I can't really provide the answer in JS or PHP here, it's a lot of code. You should try to figure out which one of the available technologies you're most familiar with, so that your learning curve won't be that steep.

Comment: OK, I think I had copied a java-script code from somewhere that made that calculator work.. I think the data was a script. the variables and.. equations, the html part was only to wrap it up nicely.. :S